# I can't insert the header into the main file

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make quicksort program and I really need help with connecting all files to main.
So, as you can see I have a so-so quicksort code and all would be fine if not this problem

```
"error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl keyboard_method(int *,int)" (?keyboard_method@@YAXPEAHH@Z) referenced in function main
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl random_method(int *,int)" (?random_method@@YAXPEAHH@Z) referenced in function main
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl read_from_file_method(int *,int)" (?read_from_file_method@@YAXPEAHH@Z) referenced in function main".
```

I don't know how to fix it, help me,please.

this is code for choice_of_method.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <fstream> 
#include "choice_of_method.h"

using namespace std;

void keyboard_method(int* array, int array_size) {
    int element;
    cout << "Элемент массива не должен быть ниже 0" << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < array_size; i++) // Заполнение массива вводимыми значениями
    {
        int element;
        cin >> element;

        if (element < 0) {
            cout << "Вы ввели недоступное значение элемента массива";
            break;
        }
        else {
            array[i] = element;
        }
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < array_size; j++)
    {
        cout << array[j] << endl;
    }

}


void random_method(int* array, int array_size) {
    srand(time(NULL));
    int max_num;
    cout << "Введите максимальное значение элемента(Не должно превышать 99): ";
    cin >> max_num;

    if (max_num > 99 || max_num < 0) {
        cout << "Вы ввели недоступное значение элемента массива";
    }
    else {
        for (int i = 0; i < array_size; i++)
        {
            array[i] = rand() % max_num;
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < array_size; j++)
        {
            cout << array[j] << endl;
        }
    }
}

void read_from_file_method(int* array,int array_size) {

    string file_name;
    cout << "Укажите имя файла и формат: ";
    cin >> file_name;

    ofstream File(file_name);
    cout << "Заполните файл" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < array_size; i++)
    {
        int element;
        cin >> element;
        File << element << " ";
        //array[i] = element;
    }
    File.close();
    /*
    File.open(file_name);
    if (File) 
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < array_size; i++)
        {
            File >> array[i];
            cout << array[i];
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        cout << "Файла не существует.";
        EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    File.close();
    */
}

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");
    return 0;
}
```

this code is for main

```
#include <iostream>
#include "choice_of_method.h"

using namespace std;

void quicksort(int* array, int size_of_array) {
    int id_last_element = size_of_array - 1;
    int id_fist_element = 0;
    int flag = 1;
    int pivot = 0;
    cout << size_of_array << endl;
    while (id_fist_element != id_last_element)
    {
        if (flag % 2 != 0)
        {
            if (array[pivot] > array[id_last_element])
            {
                cout << array[pivot] << " Меняется с " << array[id_last_element] << endl;
                swap(array[pivot], array[id_last_element]);
                pivot = id_last_element;
                cout << "Array: ";
                for (int k = 0; k < size_of_array; k++)
                {
                    cout << array[k] << " ";
                }
                cout << endl;
                id_fist_element++;
                flag++;
            }
            else {
                id_last_element--;
            }
        }
        else if (flag % 2 == 0)
        {
            if (array[pivot] < array[id_fist_element])
            {
                cout << array[pivot] << " Меняется с " << array[id_fist_element] << endl;
                swap(array[pivot], array[id_fist_element]);
                pivot = id_fist_element;
                for (int k = 0; k < size_of_array; k++)
                {
                    cout << array[k] << " ";
                }
                cout << endl;
                id_last_element--;
                flag++;
            }
            else {
                id_fist_element++;
            }
        }
    }
}


int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");

    int array_size; // Размер массива
    cout << "ВНИМАНИЕ! Размер массива не должен превышать 40" << endl;
    cout << "Введите размер массива: ";
    cin >> array_size;

    if (array_size > 40) {
        cout << "Вводимое значение массива превышает 40" << endl;
        return 0;
    }


    int* array_1{new int[array_size] }; // Объявление динамического массива


    // 1 ИЗ 3 МЕТОДОВ ЗАПОЛНЕНИЯ МАССИВА(ПЕРЕНЕСТИ В ОТДЕЛЬНЫЙ ФАЙЛ)

    int flag;
    cin >> flag;

    switch (flag)
    {
    case 1:
        keyboard_method(array_1, array_size);
        break;

    case 2:
        random_method(array_1, array_size);
        break;

    case 3:
        read_from_file_method(array_1, array_size);
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
    
    // Далле происходит quicksort

    quicksort(array_1, array_size);

    delete[] array_1;

    return 0;
}
```

.

I was trying to fix it by changing in project properties entry point:main in linker and subsystem:windows also in linker

Comment: Why are you defining `int main()` in both the files? I would recommend using a [good c++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) as any beginner c++ book explain how to split function etc into header and source files.

Comment: It's recommended to use **std::vector** instead of **C_style** arrays.

Comment: @user12002570 Sorry,bro I don't have time for this, I need to finish this project like in a 2 weeks.

Comment: @Mahdy.n Unfortunately in the assignment for my project it is written to use only C_styles arrays

Comment: @user561459  The problem is that c++ is a very complicated(and difficult) language to learn. It takes years to learn it properly. And the only good way to learn it is using the good c++ books.

Comment: @user12002570 Yes, I know that,bro. But I need to use c++ as language for this project. And I don't have a time to study it. So I'm asking a lot of basic questions(like above one) on this kind of forums.

Comment: Try to reduce your problem to get better feedback: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Then post your complete code (and include the header in question). What environment are you on, how do you compile your code ?

Comment: If you do find the time to read up on things, might want to start here: https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/introduction-to-the-compiler-linker-and-libraries/                  https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/header-files/

Comment: StackOverflow is not a forum. You are looking in the wrong place.

Comment: If you need a C++ code and you don't want to learn C++, consider hiring a paid developer.